# Merge audio by timestamps

Tags: json, audio, ffmpeg

Here example of JSON, where src - path to audio file, time - milliseconds, from  start where audio should be played.

So question, how can I merge whese files in one WAV or MP3, where this files will be played on it's timestamps?
Every file can play on same time as another.

So, as scheme, created MP3/WAV should contain something like this:

-----|firstFile-0:02--|ended

----------|secondFile-0:03|ended

------------------------------------------|thirdFile-0:23---------|ended

-------------------------------|silence-|-------------

```
{
0:
{
src: "/audio/DRUMNBass/HITS/DNB_VOICEFX001_160_C_SL2.WAV",
time: 803
}

1:
{
src:"/audio/DRUMNBass/HITS/DNB_VOICEFX001_160_C_SL2.WAV"
time:812
}

2:
{
src:"/audio/DRUMNBass/DRUMS/RNB_BEATS006_160_X_SL2.WAV"
time:1317
}

3:
{
src:"/audio/DRUMNBass/DRUMS/RNB_BEATS006_160_X_SL2.WAV"
time:1318
}

4:
{
src:"/audio/DRUMNBass/SINTH/DNB_SYNTH105_160_C_SL2.WAV"
time:2054
}

5:
{
src:"/audio/DRUMNBass/SINTH/DNB_SYNTH105_160_C_SL2.WAV"
time:2054
}

6:
{
src:"/audio/DRUMNBass/SINTH/DNB_SYNTH105_160_C_SL2.WAV"
time:2055
}

7:
{
src:"/audio/DRUMNBass/BASS/DNB_BASS018_160_C_SL2.WAV"
time:2290
}

8:
{
src:"/audio/DRUMNBass/BASS/DNB_BASS018_160_C_SL2.WAV"
time:2290
}

}
```

Console command of FFmpeg will be sufficient ))

Comment: See [here](http://superuser.com/q/1092291/114058).

Comment: What is 1 and b in [1]234|234[b] ?

Comment: `[1]` is an input label pad and refers to the 2nd input (index starts from 0), so `-i second.mka` in that example. `[b]` is the output label pad. You can feed it as an input in another filter (like in the amix) or map it for output.

Comment: so, I can't write [1]234|234[1] if I just need merge files?

Comment: No. There may be namespace collision. How would you distinguish `1` without adelay from `1` with?

Comment: Thanks :) but how I can merge, say, 50 files? [44]123|123[bb] ?

Comment: I think `amix` has a limit of 32, but test it. If it does, do an amix of first 32 files, and a separate amix of next 18 files, and then an amix of those two outputs.

Comment: @Mulvya , I have a problem ) when I amix of previously amix it's put silence, instead of mixed sounds on start, and played only last part, that mixed to previously created. So, if first created track is 1 minute length, then next track, created from this one and new - 1 minute of silence and then - new sounds

Comment: Show the command and console output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115875/discussion-between-koiiiey-and-mulvya).

Comment: @Mulvya output pasted in chat

Comment: And strange thing - sound volume increases from the beginning to the end, so on first second it 0, end on the last second - full